# Make reference to a file in a regular expression

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have two files. One is a SALESORDERLIST, which goes like this

```
ProductID;ProductDesc
1,potatoes 1 kg.
2,tomatoes 2 k
3,bottles of whiskey 2 un.
4,bottles of beer 40 gal
```

(ProductID;ProductDesc) header is actually not in the file, so disregard it.
In another file, POSSIBLEUNITS, I have -you guessed- the possible units, and their equivalencies:

```
u;u.;un;un.;unit
k;k.;kg;kg.,kilograms
```

This is my first day with regular expressions and I would like to know how can I get the entries in SALESORDERLIST, whose units appear in POSSIBLEUNITS. In my example, I would like to exclude entry 4 since 'gal' is not listed in POSSIBLEUNITS file.

I say regex, since I have a further criteria that needs to be matched:

```
egrep "^[0-9]+;{1}[^; ][a-zA-Z ]+" SALESORDERLIST
```

From those resultant entries, I want to get those ending in valid units.

Thanks!

Comment: You should probably take a look at tools like `awk` and `grep` to achieve what you want, a regex by itself, doesn't parse files, it parses strings.   
***A regular expression is a special text string for describing a search pattern.*** http://www.regexbuddy.com/regex.html

Comment: @Tuga It *could* be done just in bash, though.

Comment: @ooga as far as I know `awk` and `grep` run in bash, but OP won't achieve the desired result only with a regex.

Comment: @iL_Marto Don't post it here, update your question.

Comment: @Tuga Of course they "run in bash" (well, not exactly *in* bash, but they can be run *from* bash). I'm just saying that it could be done with just bash itself since bash can read lines from a file and can match subexpressions with simple regexes. I'm not saying it's the best way to do it, but it's an interesting exercise.

Comment: Your input file does not match the regexp (comma, not semicolon). Which is correct?

Answer (score 0):

One way of achieving what you want is:

```
cat SALESORDERLIST | egrep "\b(u|u\.|un|un\.|unit|k|k\.|kg|kg\.|kilograms)\b"


1,potatoes 1 kg.
2,tomatoes 2 k
3,bottles of whiskey 2 un.
```

> The metacharacter **\b** is an **anchor** that allows you to perform a "**whole words only**" search using
>   a regular expression in the form of **\bword\b**.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a bash script, say called `findunit.sh`:

```
while read line
do
    match=$(egrep -E "^[0-9]+,{1}[^, ][a-zA-Z ]+" <<< $line)    
    name=${match##* }
        # echo "$name..."
        found=$(egrep "$name" /pathtofile/units.txt) 
        # echo "xxx$found"
        [ -n "$found" ] && echo $line
done < $1
```

Then run with:

```
findunit.sh SALESORDERLIST
```

My output from this is:

```
1,potatoes 1 kg.
2,tomatoes 2 k
3,bottles of whiskey 2 un.
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of doing it completely in bash:

```
declare -A units

while read line; do
  while [ -n "$line" ]; do
    i=`expr index $line ";"`
    if [[ $i == 0 ]]; then
      units[$line]=1
      break
    fi
    units[${line:0:$((i-1))}]=1
    line=${line#*;}
  done
done < POSSIBLEUNITS

while read line; do
  unit=${line##* }
  if [[ ${units[$unit]} == 1 ]]; then
    echo $line
  fi
done < SALESORDERLIST
```